# SQL Spatial index and clustered index

Tags: azure-sql-database, clustered-index, spatial-index

I am creating a spatial index on a geography column in SQL Server Azure Server  like below..

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sp_idx ON TableA(GeographyAreaCode)  USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID WITH (GRIDS = (LEVEL_1 = LOW, LEVEL_2 = LOW, LEVEL_3 = HIGH, LEVEL_4 = HIGH), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, DROP_EXISTING = ON)

Now I've observed that two indexes with the given name sp_idx are being created - one spatial and the other as Clustered index..

Does SQL Server create a mandatory clustered index with the spatial index?

Also If I have to delete this index, will it delete the associated Clustered index also?

Many Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all SQL azure tables require a clustered index:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cir

This is by design.  To answer your questions:

Removing the special index should not remove the clustered index.  SQL Azure probably created the clustered index, because you didn't have one and it is a requirement in SQL Azure.  I would manage clustered indexes on my own not have SQL Azure put default ones on there, just to satisfy requirements.

**Update**

You can only have ONE clustered index on any SQL table.  There are no other clustered indexes that are managed on a table with a clustered index already existing.  I hope that helps with your comment below.

Comment: Well the table already has a Clustered index on a primary key.. The geography column is not the primary key.. My question is whether a spatial index created on a geo data column also creates a clustered/non clustered index on the same column?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bart.. I checked the database again today and it's weird that I found two clustered indexes on the same table.. The one that I mentioned earlier, with the is_primary_key value = 0 and the regular clustered index on the table.. Note that the regular clustered index is based on a composite primary key (e.g. country code + postal code)

Comment: What do you mean two clustered indexes?  There can be a primary and a clustered index and those can be different and both on one table.  Something is wrong if there are two clustered indexes on a single table.